# How to optimize canvas rendering for dynamic loading HTML5 game world?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, web-worker

I've been working on an isometric game engine for my own game. Currently, it's a big, open world with the map data being retrieved dynamically from the Node.js server.

To understand what I'm doing... for the most part it's a tile based world. So each map has a max number of cols,rows (19) and each world has a max number of maps by col,row (6). So it's a 6x6 world map consisting of 19x19 tiles per map. Whenever the players move onto a new map/region, the client requests a 3x3 matrix of the surrounding maps with the center map being the map the player is currently on. This part is pretty well optimized.

My problem, however, is finding a great way to optimize the drawing onto the canvas. Currently, I don't have a lot of lag doing so, but I also have a fast computer, but I worry that at times it could cause others to lag / mess with the rendering of other graphics.

Basically, how I have it working right now is when the data is sent back from the server, it adds each map and all the tile images for each col/row it has to render into a buffer. Each loop of the game loop, it will basically render a small section of the 25 tiles onto the specific map's hidden canvas. When all of the requested maps are done rendering (after a few game loops), the camera will go ahead and merge these hidden maps into 1 big map canvas of the 3x3 matrix (by slicing parts from the hidden canvases and merging them onto the new canvas).

Ideally I would love this whole process to be async. but I've been looking into web workers and apparently they do not support canvas well. Has anyone come up with a process to do something similar and keep it well optimized?

Thanks!

Comment: The best "optimization" is do as few draw calls as possible. Just because you have data from the server doesn't mean you need to draw it when it's off screen.

Comment: How big are the tiles (in pixels)??

Comment: @Blindman67 128x64 image for each tile

Comment: Hard to know what you are doing. Are all the tiles completely unique, is there any way to abstract data (eg the background texture is similar can be dropped from the tiles reducing the data load) are there any other common elements between tiles?

Comment: @Blindman67 the tiles are technically able to be completely unique from eachother which is why I"m not focused on a static background image. Basically, I have them being rendered onto offscreen canvases and then merged into one large map on a canvas because I was under the impression that it improves performance when you're drawing an image in a canvas onto another canvas. Would it be more beneficial just to render all of the tiles in viewport per frame, each frame instead of just grabbing slices of the hidden canvases?

Comment: Depend on the minimum target device and available GPU RAM. Considering the max map size, 19 tiles * 128 pixels for a width of 2432 this could be a bit large for basic devices. Attempting to render such an image would incur some paging (swapping CPU RAM to GPU RAM) a big slowdown. You're on the edge for lower performance devices. I would go for offscreen buffer that is one tile (integer multiple) larger than the display size. BUT if constant scrolling then I would render tiles directly to screen. Optionally you can degrad quality if frame rate drops. For average devices you don't have a worry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of rendering a 19x19 grid in each frame.  A new random tile is added from right to left top to bottom in each frame.  The grid is rendered in the same order and you can see that this works for overlapping tiles.

I think it's best to save each tile and make a function that renders the entire grid. So if the player gets updates in the 3x3 surrounding area then download and keep those tiles and re-render the entire grid.

*update*
I provided a function to eliminate overdraw and a toggle.  This may increase performance for some people.  It draws from bottom to top left to right. This draws the overlaying items first and with globalCompositeOperation "distination-over" tells the canvas to leave existing pixels alone when adding new content. This should mean less work to do in putting pixels on the canvas as it's not drawing over unused pixels.

```js
var cols = 19;
var tile_width = 32;
var rows = 19;
var tile_height = 16;
var y_offset = 64;

var h_tw = tile_width / 2;
var h_th = tile_height / 2;

var frames = 0;
var fps = "- fps";

setInterval(function(){
  fps = frames + " fps";
  frames = 0;
}, 1000);

var can = document.getElementById('tile');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var wcan = document.getElementById('world');
var wctx = wcan.getContext('2d');
wcan.width = cols * tile_width;
wcan.height = rows * tile_height + y_offset;

var tiles = initTiles();


document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.innerHTML == 'renderWorld') {
    renderFn = renderWorldNoOverdraw;
    this.innerHTML = "renderWorldNoOverdraw";
  } else {
    renderFn = renderWorld;
    this.innerHTML = "renderWorld";
  }
});

//renderWorld();
var ani_x = cols;
var ani_y = 0;
var renderFn = renderWorld;
ani();


function initTiles () {
  var tiles = [];
  
  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      var can = document.createElement('canvas');
      can.width=tile_width;
      can.height=tile_height+y_offset;
      row[x]=can;
    }
    tiles[y] = row;
  }  
  return tiles;
}

function ani() {
  var can = tiles[ani_y][--ani_x]
  
  if (ani_x == 0) ani_x = cols, ani_y++;
  ani_y %= rows;
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  randTile(can, ctx);
  
  renderFn();
  requestAnimationFrame(ani);
}

// renders from bottom left to right and skips
// drawing over pixels already present.
function renderWorldNoOverdraw() {
  frames++;
  wctx.clearRect(0,0,wcan.width,wcan.height);
  wctx.save();
  wctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  wctx.translate(0, y_offset);
  var x_off = 0;
  var y_off = 0;
  var y_off2 = 0;
  for (var y = rows; y--;) {
    x_off = (cols * h_tw)- ((rows-y) * h_tw);
    y_off = y * h_th + tile_height;
    y_off2 = y_off;
    for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      var can = tiles[y][x];
      wctx.drawImage(can, x_off, y_off2 + y_offset);
      y_off2 -= h_th;
      x_off += h_tw;
    }
  }
  wctx.translate(0,-y_offset);
  wctx.fillStyle = "#ddaadd";
  wctx.fillRect(0,0,wcan.width, wcan.height);
  wctx.restore();
  wctx.fillStyle= "black";
  wctx.fillText(fps, 10, 10);
}

function renderWorld() {
  frames++;
  wctx.fillStyle = "#CCEEFF";
  wctx.fillRect(0, 0, wcan.width, wcan.height);
  wctx.save();
  wctx.translate(0, y_offset);
  var x_off = 0;
  var y_off = 0;
  var y_off2 = 0;
  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    x_off = (cols * h_tw) + (y * h_tw) - h_tw;
    y_off = y * h_th;
    y_off2 = y_off;
    for (var x = cols; x--;) {
      var can = tiles[y][x];
      wctx.drawImage(can, x_off, y_off2 - 64);
      y_off2 += h_th;
      x_off -= h_tw;
    }
    y_off += h_th;
    x_off -= h_tw;
  }
  wctx.restore();
    wctx.fillStyle= "black";
  wctx.fillText(fps, 10, 10);
}

function randTile(can, ctx) {
  var maxH = can.height - 24;
  var ranH = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxH);
  var h = Math.max(ranH, 1);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(0, can.height - 16);

  ctx.moveTo(0, 8);
  ctx.lineTo(16, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(32, 8);
  ctx.lineTo(16, 16);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 8);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#333333";
  ctx.stroke();

  // random floor color
  var colors = ["#dd9933", "#22aa00", "#66cccc", "#996600"];
  ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  ctx.fill();

  // random building
  if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) == 0) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(8, 8);
    ctx.lineTo(8, -h - 4);
    ctx.lineTo(16, -h);
    ctx.lineTo(16, 12);
    ctx.lineTo(8, 8);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#333333";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(16, 12);
    ctx.lineTo(16, -h);
    ctx.lineTo(24, -h - 4);
    ctx.lineTo(24, 8);
    ctx.lineTo(16, 12);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#999999";
    ctx.fill()

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(16, -h);
    ctx.lineTo(24, -h - 4);
    ctx.lineTo(16, -h - 8);
    ctx.lineTo(8, -h - 4);
    ctx.moveTo(16, -h);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CCCCCC";
    ctx.fill()
  }
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">renderWorld</button><br/>
<canvas id='tile' width="32" height="32" style="display:none"></canvas>
<canvas id="world" width="608" height="368">
</canvas>
```

Comment: interesting, I always wondered about doing that, but... if you save every sprite or graphic to it's own separate canvas won't that be a little too much? Or have you noticed a change in performance by doing that? I was always under the impression , yes it's best to yse multiple canvases for layering / rendering, but too many could slow your browser and that could potentially be hundreds of canvases. @wolfhammer

Comment: @Ryan you're right that it takes more resources.  I see that you have larger tiles so this might hog your resources.  You're doing a kind of double buffering approach where you draw everything off screen then added it to the display once it's complete.  This requires more resources for the large off screen canvas but makes it so maps show up completed and don't materialize on the main canvas. If you don't care about people seeing the parts load in then it's okay to draw on the main canvas and discard the hidden canvases.

Comment: Thanks Wolfhammer for your help! This is awesome information! :)